# How to share android directories over LAN using SMB protocol

Tags: file-management, cifs

I want my hone to be used as network drive, by sharing folders over network. So that I can access it from My windows PC. I want to use SMA protocol for that.
I am using OnePlus One, CM12.1 OS with ES file explorer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a rooted phone, you can use one of these two apps that let you set up a samba server: [Samba Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.sambaserver) or [SambaDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sambadroid) (they are portings of Samba for Linux). Of course, you can find and use any other equivalent app. Root is required because Windows doesn't recognise non-conventional servers (i.e. which use non-standard ports), so you must be able to change the default ports on your phone.
If your device is not rooted, then you can:

- create a Samba server with your PC, granting read/write privileges to the shared folders
- use Es file explorer as a samba client (the smb protocol is built in)

In order to do it, follow these steps in Es (I will cover only the android side, assuming you know/will find out how to set up servers on PC):

- open side menu, go to 'network' and choose LAN
- touch the plus sign at the bottom right corner, this interface will pop up:
  [image: popup]
- leave the 'domain' field empty
- fill in the server name (local ip address of your PC), and username and password that you set up for your server
- do not check the 'anonymous' box (if your server isn't password protected then check it)
- choose a name for the server to be displayed on your phone
  And that's it.
  This should do the trick (as long as you enable r/w on your PC), doesn't require root and is well built in to Es file manager.